# configure the broker

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ as message Broker with something like 140 Topics. 
I am facing a problem that the broker keeps old messages, instead of discarding them in order to send new messages (so clients gets old data instead of current data). 
How do I configure the broker not to keep old messages? the important data is allways the last data, so if a consumer didn't get data, he will get next time the most updated. 
I have configured on producer TTL as 250, but it doesn't seem to work... 
One other thing, 
How can I disable the creation of advisory topics?

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

> Advisory messages are required for
>   dynamic network broker topologies as
>   NetworkConnectors subscribe to
>   advisory messages. In the absence of
>   advisories, a network must be
>   statically configured.

Beware that using `advisorySupport="false"` will **NOT** work with dynamic network brokers as per this reference page: http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html

Comment: I've added advisorySupport="false" to broker in activemq.xml because in code not use explicit broker. It's work fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a durable consumer to receive these messages from the topics concerned? If so, the broker will be holding on to all messages sent when you were disconnected. Switch to a regular consumer in order to only see "current" messages on the topic.

To prevent the creation of advisory topics and their associated messages add the `advisorySupport="false"` property to the `<broker />` element of the ActiveMQ config file.